# Poor performance of Microsoft UI Automation Library

Tags: performance, user-interface, automation

I am currently trying to automate a Windows Forms application by using the Microsoft UI Automation Library and C#, but I have big problems concerning the performance. The Identification of single elements by using a `PropertyCondition` or iterating over all elements of a window takes very long (up to 4 minutes). As soon as I have a `AutomationElement`, everything is fine (e.g. `GetCurrentPropertyValue` reacts within 100ms).

The poor performance only applies to one application. I don't have access to the source but if something needs to be changed or checked, I can talk to the responsible programmer. As far as I know, some events (e.g. paint) were overwritten for the application. A typical window of the application contains about ~100 elements which are found by the `FindAll` method.

I also tried the COM interface of the UI automation library, which is about two times faster but this does not really solve the problem.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem or experienced similar behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer when we took a closer look at the main loop. In most cases Application.Run is used to start up the main window and run the application but for some reason the following code was used:

```
[...]    
    MainForm.Show();
    while DoStop == false
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
[...]
```

As the Microsoft UI Automation Library uses window messages, all the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); summed up and made the object detection become really slow. This does not happen, if Application.Run is used.

Comment: so if understood you correctly, poor performance was basically related to badly written application under test, not to the UI automation framework itself?

Comment: Is this Thread.Sleep code on the UI that is having the automation used against it?  Or the application that's performing the automation?  Btw, what are the odds that a 4 year old SO post would get its first 2 comments within 2 days of each other?

Comment: @Tobias: Whoever wrote that code with Thread.Sleep was a complete fool. Sadly your answer does not help all the others who also observe that UI Automation is extremely slow. Even without that kind of stupid programming errors in the automated application you will find that UIA is a big heap of crap. It has lots of bugs, a lot of functionality is missing, it is not thread safe and it is extremely slow.

Comment: The solution to slow performance is to use the new IUIAutomationElement COM interface (since Windows 7) See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768046/system-windows-automation-is-extremely-slow