# System.Windows.Automation is extremely slow

Tags: c#, com, ui-automation

System.Windows.Automation is EXTREMELY slow.

I execute:

```
element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
```

Obtaining only 30 child elements may take 1000ms on a very fast computer.

I have even seen it hanging forever while getting the child elements of a Tree in a QT application.

Is this a known problem?
I cannot find any usefull answer after googling a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`System.Windows.Automation` is EXTREMELY **slow**.

`System.Windows.Automation` is full of **bugs**. It may not return all children of an AutomationElement, which is a very severe bug.

Apart from that the implementation is **not thread safe**.

`System.Windows.Automation` is deprecated. Do not use it!

In the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076(v=vs.85).aspx) you find the following note:

> UI Automation was first available in Windows XP as part of the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework. Although an unmanaged C++ API was also
>   published at that time, the usefulness of client functions was limited
>   because of interoperability issues. For Windows 7, the API has been
>   rewritten in the Component Object Model (COM).
>    Although the library functions introduced in the earlier version of
>   UI Automation are still documented, they should not be used in new
>   applications.

The solution to slow performance is to use the new **IUIAutomationElement** COM interface instead of the old System.Windows.Automation C# interface. After that the code will be running **lightning fast**!

Apart from that the new interface offers much more patterns and Microsoft is extending it continously. In the Windows 10 SDK (UIAutomationClient.h and UIAutomationCore.h) several patterns and properties have been added which are not available in the .NET Automation framework.

The following patterns are available in the COM version of UIAutomation which do not exist in System.Windows.Automation:

- IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern
- IUIAutomationObjectModelPattern
- IUIAutomationAnnotationPattern
- IUIAutomationTextPattern2
- IUIAutomationStylesPattern
- IUIAutomationSpreadsheetPattern
- IUIAutomationSpreadsheetItemPattern
- IUIAutomationTransformPattern2
- IUIAutomationTextChildPattern
- IUIAutomationDragPattern
- IUIAutomationDropTargetPattern
- IUIAutomationTextEditPattern
- IUIAutomationCustomNavigationPattern

Additionally the following Control types have been added:

- AppBar
- SemanticZoom

Additionally the following Element's have been added:

- IUIAutomationElement2
- IUIAutomationElement3
- IUIAutomationElement4

And what concerns the **bugs**: The new COM UIAutomation Framework is very well designed and I could not find bugs on the **client side** of the framework which is a great progress compared to `System.Windows.Automation`. But several missing features and even bugs on the **server side** of the framework. On the server side each GUI framework must implement an UIAutomation provider (see [MSDN: Interfaces for Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). So these problems differ depending on what type of application you are automating because each GUI framework has it's own problems:

In the **Native Windows GUI** features are missing: Lots of controls do not implement the patterns that they should implement. For example a **SplitButton** in a native Toolbar should implement the `Invoke` pattern to click the button and the `ExpandCollapse` pattern to open the drop-down menu. But the `ExpandCollapse` pattern is missing which makes it difficult to use SplitButtons. If you obtain a Toolbar SplitButton by `IUIAutomation->ElementFromPoint()` and then ask for it's parent you will get a crippled element. And the **Pager** control cannot be automated at all.

Also in **WPF applications** there are controls that are implemented buggy by Microsoft: For example if you have a **Calendar** control you see two buttons at the top to switch to the next/previous month. If you execute the `Invoke` pattern on these buttons you will get an `UIA_E_NOTSUPPORTED` error. But this is not a bug on the client side of the framework, because for other buttons the `Invoke` pattern works correctly. This is a bug in the WPF Automation server. And if you test `IUIAutomationTextRange` with a WPF RichTextBox, you will find that several commands are not implemented: `Select()` and `ScrollIntoView()` do simply nothing.

For **.NET Forms applications** Microsoft did not make much effort to support them. The .NET **Calendar** control cannot be automated at all. The entire control is not even recognized as Calendar. It has the ControlType "Pane" with no child elements in it. The same applies to the **DateTimePicker**. And for complex controls like **DataGrid** and **PropertyGrid** the only implemented pattern is `LegacyIAccessible` which is a poor support. These controls should implement at least the `Table` and the `Grid` and the `ScrollItem` pattern.

Also **Internet Explorer** cannot be automated because elements outside the visible area cannot be scrolled automatically into view due to missing coordinates. (The Bounds are returned as an empty rectangle) And the `ScrollItem` pattern is not implemented. (Yes, I know that Internet Explorer has been replaced with Edge in Windows 10, but the UIAutomation framework exists since Windows 7 and Microsoft did not implement a usefull automation support in Internet Explorer in all these years)

I saw even complete **crashes** of the automated application. For example Visual Studio and TotalCommander will crash if you execute certain automation commands on a certain control. Here - once again - the bug lies in the server side implementation of the framework.

**Summary:** We have a great framework with limited usefullness. The Microsoft team that developed the new UIAutomation framework did a great job, but the other areas in Microsoft (the native GUI, WPF, .NET and Internet Explorer team) do not support this framework. This is very sad because only a small effort would have to be made to offer a better functionality. But it seems that the users who use UIAutomation in the first place (handicapped people) are not a profitable market.

Comment: Instead of calling most of these problems as bugs, I would call them lack of documentation / understanding. One thing I should point you is, TotalCommander crashing is not a UIA problem. UIA, after all is a mediator between the UI client app (your controller code) and the UI server (in this case TotalCommander). You should be knowing what the application-under-control will do each time you use a UIA call.

Comment: What I write has absolutely nothing to do with a lack of understanding. I'am software developer since 35 years with a very deep understanding of Windows. The UIAutomation framework has a server side and a client side. Both comunicate via IPC. TotalCommander is just one example. The same crash appears in Visual Studio. Both use the native Windows GUI. On the server side there is a severe bug which pulls down the entire application. So why do you think that this is NOT a bug? I redacted my answer anew to make it more clear. Please read it again.

Comment: It seems that you have the idea that TotalCommander brings his own Automation framework. This is wrong. When you automate an app you communicate with the automation provider of the GUI framework, which is the server side of automation. And here are the bugs located. If an app crashes during automation you have a severe bug on the provider side (=server side) of the UIA framework. E.g: To get the coordinates of an element you call IRawElementProviderFragment->get_BoundingRectangle(). For more information see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: An Automation provider tells UIA which element corresponds to a Window handle, where it is located on the screen, who are it's children, if it is visible, etc. Both sides, the client and server, run in UiAutomationCore.dll which you will find loaded into both processes: the automated process and the automating process. And for each GUI framework an individual automation provider is used: WPF has other controls than a DirectUI user interface and so the bugs differ with each GUI framework. And TotalCommander is automated with the native Windows GUI provider which has the above mentioned bugs.

Comment: I've seen my share of problems around UIA, and again, the bug you're mentioning (the totalcommander one) is not UIA's, it's the provider interface implementation of the corresponding call, in this case WinForms. But it should be a specific way of using a winforms item on the server that caused the problem. (cont'd on next comment)

Comment: So depending on which framework you use, and how that framework implements the provider or disables them (to completely close UIA interface, for example), or how the specific application uses a combination of elements all effect the result of the UIA call. That means the whole architecture should be designed correctly including uia client, uia provider layer, and how the uia provider logic is used with the combination of the elements (I'm stressing that because in case of a tree traversal of elements things are different than a flat children model for a simple client Find call)

Comment: You write: "the bug you're mentioning (the totalcommander one) is not UIA's, it's the provider interface implementation of the corresponding call". So you decided that the provider side does not belong to UIA. But this is wrong. The provider side is also part of the UIA framework. As I wrote in my updated answer: UIA consists of a client side and a server (= provider) side. And the bugs that I describe are on the server side of UIA.

Comment: As the author of FlaUI (which supports UIA2 and UIA3), I can tell you that UIA2 is usually still better for WinForms applications. There are some issues with UIA3 and WinForms (eg. the RangeSlider does not work correctly) and it is often better to use UIA2 even thou it is slower.