# How to use IUIAutomation in powershell?

Tags: powershell, com, ui-automation

I want to use UI automation. As described in other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768047/3402056) System.Windows.Automation is deprecated. So my question - how to use COM IUIAutomation with powershell?

There is commandlet New-Object with -ComObject parameter. That parameter accepts name of a creatable CoClass? Where can I get it?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to obtain IUIAutomation COM object. `New-Object -ComObject IUIAutomation` not work.

Comment: That's because its the name of an interface. You have to give the name of a creatable CoClass.

Comment: ok. I understand it. Where I can find name of CoClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Windows.Automation is somewhat deprecated but:

- it works fine enough for most operations, and I'm not sure performance issues mentioned in the linked article are related to the fact it's deprecated.
- it relies on the native Windows-provided *UIAutomationCore.dll* assembly which contains all the new code anyway, so my guess System.Windows.Automation is indirectly using the new COM objects underneath.
- I believe it's the only API you can use from PowerShell, because you can only use COM Automation objects (not to be confused with System.Windows.Automation), ie: .NET, VB6, Scripting, etc. not pure IUnknown (not IDispatch) interfaces.

As an alternative you could use [UI Automation COM-to-.NET Adapter](https://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/) which is a more recent version of the UIAutomationClient assembly (written by a Microsoft guy), but this is only necessary if you need Windows 8 UIA new properties and patterns, or if you observe it does work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code-snippet to start with:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName @('UIAutomationClient', 'UIAutomationTypes')
$ae = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]
$obj1 = $ae::FromHandle($winHandle)
```