Installing UIAutomation PowerShell Module
I would like to install the UIAutomation PowerShell module on my PowerShell ISE. I have used the following command for this:
Install-Module -Name UIAutomationClient

or
Install-Module -Name UIAutomation

However, neither of these worked.
I can't find anything on the Internet that I could download. Apparently these modules should already be pre-installed.

Can you tell us why you want to install a module you can't find any information about online? What's the end game here?

I know this is bad form to be off topic but consider using VSCode instead of PowerShell ISE. The ISE has many annoying features and vscode is better in pretty much every way. As for your question, this answer seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160480/how-to-use-iuiautomation-in-powershell, there's not a powershell module for it, you have to manually import the underlying DLL, or use the accepted answer which has an alternative.

Thank your very much. Do you know where I can find the DLL-Files?

You just type the code they show Add-Type -AssemblyName @('UIAutomationClient', 'UIAutomationTypes'), etc, powershell finds the dll for you. It works for me but I also have visual studio installed which maybe put these dlls somewhere powershell can find it, give it a try if it works then you're good. The linked answer says it's "Windows-provided" so you probably have it already.
