# Firefox Quantum get url (VB.Net/C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, firefox

Anyone knows how to get the url from firefox quantum? I know for firefox:

```
 Dim DdeClient As New DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo")
 DdeClient.Connect()
 Dim URL As String = DdeClient.Request("URL", Integer.MaxValue)
 DdeClient.Disconnect()
 URL = Split(URL, """,""")(0)
 URL = Split(URL, """")(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself with this

```
        Dim ProcessFireFox As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")
        If ProcessFireFox.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("firefox not found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each Firefox As Process In ProcessFireFox
            If Firefox.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then Continue For
            Dim AutomationElement As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement = System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(Firefox.MainWindowHandle)
            For Each Elm As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement In AutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document))
                Dim BAutomationPattern As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationPattern() = Elm.GetSupportedPatterns()
                Dim BValuePattern As System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern = DirectCast(Elm.GetCurrentPattern(BAutomationPattern(0)), System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern)
                MsgBox(BValuePattern.Current.Value.ToString)
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Hello, Is your code still working? I did tried but without success. @PeterJ

Comment: it's working for me but it takes a while to get the url

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768047/2835505) and considering the comment of Peter: 
`it's working for me but it takes a while to get the url`

I wrote the following code. Maybe it could be helpful to someone:

```
  Process[] lFFs = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");

                    for (int i = 0; i < lEs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement ee = lEs.GetElement(i);
                        if (ee != null && ee.CurrentName  != null &&
 (ee.CurrentName.Contains("search") || ee.CurrentName.Contains("navigation")))                       
    { // For spanish you can use: (ee.CurrentName.Contains("de búsqueda") || ee.CurrentName==  "Barra de navegación")

                            lEs = ee.FindAll(UIAutomationClient.TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, c);
                            if (lEs.Length > 0)
                                i = 0;
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    object obj = ee.GetCurrentPattern(10002); // 10002: ValuePattern

                                    if (obj != null)
                                    {
                                        string sUrl = ((UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationValuePattern)obj).CurrentValue;
                                        return  sUrl;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                { }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

**Important**, to make this code to work, your code must reference the COM library:  UIAutomationClient

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped disabling multi-process Firefox (Electrolysis/e10s).

In version 57.0.4 goto `about:config` and set:

`browser.tabs.remote.autostart=false (default)`
`browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2=false`