# How do I deal with the exceptions in my Visual Studio memory heap snapshot?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory

I am new to trying to optimize memory usage in Visual Studio. My C#.NET automation app increases rapidly in memory usage, and I want to prevent that from happening. I have taken a heap snapshot when it is first launched, and then another once the memory is getting high. But I don't really know what to do with these things I'm seeing in the diff.

Of particular concern to me are the `COMExceptions` and the `ElementNotAvailableExceptions`. I understand what these exceptions are, but I don't understand why I have so many in RAM or how to reduce that quantity. The `ElementNotAvailableExceptions` are each caught inside their respective functions, and thus should be gone from memory immediately after the function is complete, right? I don't save them to static variables or anything crazy like that. I'm certainly not saving `COMExceptions` either. Why would these things take up so much memory in my heap snapshots?

Also, what on earth is `ConcurrentStack + Node <Object>`? I never once use the term `ConcurrentStack` in my code and see nothing I understand when I expand it. And what do I do about it taking up so much memory?

[image: Image of heap diff]

**EDIT:** Here are the `Paths to root` displayed for the `ElementNotAvailableExceptions`, which don't seem to assist in telling me anything of value.

[image: Image of Paths to root for ElementNotAvailableExceptions]

Comment: Your question is too broad. To understand why a particular object is still alive, you have to find its way to a GC-root. Use a memory profiler for that - it will show you why the objects are still alive.

Comment: Also, if you are using the .Net Wrapper for UIA for anything more than a short lived simple use case, you are in for a world of pain. It is not too much worse to go direct against the UIA COM interfaces directly.  Note that you do have to be careful with threading if you don’t use the wrapper, though.

Comment: @Mitch, I'm using this. Is this the thing that's a pain? Or were you referring to something different? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.treewalker?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Did you try to use DebugDiag to analyse the dump ? it may more usefull than VS if you are not used to work with memory dump

Comment: Yes, that's the one that is deceptively simple.  I don't agree with all of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768047/138200 but it does give some of the history.  It is about the same complexity to hit the `IUIAutomation` interface as it is to use the wrapper - so if this is a complex use case or a mission critical use case I'd start there.  You'd start by adding a reference to `UIAutomationClient` (COM Library) instead of `System.Windows.Automation`.  Example : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2016/07/12/building-and-running-a-uia-sample-app-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why on earth an `ElementNotAvailableException` would stay in RAM (when it's encapsulated in a function, garbage collection runs regularly, and I'm not intentionally saving them to static variables). But I did get rid of my RAM issues by making sure that every `AutomationElement` was not null before trying to get its children or siblings or whatever (instead of just try-catching these exceptions, like I was doing, and then moving on in my code).

```
if (myAutomationElement != null)
{
    AutomationElement parent = walker.GetParent(myAutomationElement);
}
```